# STM32F103 stuck in PLL Ready Flag Set Loop forever!

Tags: keil

we working on stm32f103ret ic and using CMSIS library for setting GPIO Ports, so i have debuged program in keil v5.14 so in debugign mode it's stuck in line 1043 of systme_stm32f10x.c file which is this code :

```
 RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLL2ON;
/* Wait till PLL2 is ready */
while((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLL2RDY) == 1)//0
{
```

as you see in this picture:

[image: /* Wait till PLL2 is ready */]

and it's clock setting here:

[image: the clock]

So all of main.c code is here:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

void delay(void);

int main(){
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_Struct;
    uint16_t N;
    int i;

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC,ENABLE);

    GPIO_Struct.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIO_Struct.GPIO_Pin=0xFFFF; // Selects All Pins
    GPIO_Struct.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC,&GPIO_Struct);
  GPIO_Write(GPIOC,0xFFFF);

while(1){
    //GPIO_Write(GPIOC,0xAAAA);
    GPIO_Write(GPIOC,0xFFFF);

    for(i=0;i<16;++i){
        N=GPIO_ReadInputData(GPIOC);
        N=N>>1;
        GPIO_Write(GPIOC,N);
        delay();
    }
}
}

void delay(void){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<1000;++i)
        for(j=0;j<1000;++j);
}
```

and the whole project is here:

[keil files](https://www.4shared.com/s/fnu2QBKdHfi)

thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you configure appropriately for an internal clock or an external crystal **actually present and verified oscillating** ?  Questions here are required to include the critical information in the body of the question posting itself, and your question excludes the very line you claim is hanging!

Comment: this is not so big project, as you can see I paste the main.c file I the question and my board have had one external  8 M.Hz oscillators but in main.c file it is not setting the clock for MCU but in options file I have added 8 M.Hz for the clock of the project, and I added a photo of clock setting in the question, so i think there is no need anything for setting the clock.

Comment: It's not the main that should be in your question, it is *all* the code that accomplishes clock setup.  And if you are trying to use the HSE, the details of the crystal and what you found when you looked at it with a 10x probe.

Answer (score 1):

The reference manual for that part from [here](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf) says

For the register RCC->CR

> Bit 25 PLLRDY: PLL clock ready flag
>
> Set by hardware to indicate that the PLL is locked.
>
> 0: PLL unlocked
>
> 1: PLL locked

If you're waiting for the PLL to lock your loop condition should be `while((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLL2RDY) == 0)` Check the definition of `RCC_CR_PLL2RDY`, it should be 1 << 25, but the reference manual for the part you mention doesn't mention a PLL2, so it could just be a naming issue.

At the moment I suspect your PLL is managing to lock before you enter your loop, and then you never leave it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason, it was because of changing MCU series in Keil target option (Default MCU was STM32F107VC AND MCU was STM32F103RE ), so I must remove "startup_stm32f10x_lc.s" which belong to default MCU from project and inserted "startup_stm32f10x_hd.s" belong to New MCU.

as you can see in below pic it's built without any Error:

[image: pic]